# Swift - BLE command execution in Background mode in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

I want to continuously communicate with BLE device in in one of the my iOS application. Is it possible?

How can i achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please show what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by Background mode. Do you mean when the app is minimized or do you mean in background thread?

As far as being continuously connected with the BLE device is concerned then yes it is possible! Provided your BLE device is continuously powered on and available.

You'd have to search for particular service and then its characteristics using Core Bluetooth.

Mind you this could be a battery draining operation.

Suggestion would be to connect read what you want to read and disconnect.